# Convert Google Maps coordinates to pixels

Tags: java, coordinates

I have simple list of Google Maps coordinates (range 44-46 lat. and 15-17 lon.) and I have a screen size 1280x720. How can I translate those coordinates (bunch of them) in this screen size so actually my top edge of the screen would respresent 46.000000, lower edge 44.000000, left edge 15.000000 and right edge 17.000000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple.

Map 2 longitude degrees to 1280 pixels = 640 pixels / longitude degree

Map 2 latitude degrees to 720 pixels = 360 pixels /latitude degree

The rest is simple math.

Comment: But wouldn't I get it "smashed" together?

Comment: What do you mean with "smashed"? If you mean that when points are less than 1/640th (longitude) of a degree apart, they will land on the same pixel, then yes.